# Implementing a simple counter in Android

Tags: android, counter

Im trying yo implement a counter. There will be a place to show the count, and 2 buttons (++ & --).

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Edittext1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@string/cero" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Edittext1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Edittext1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/mas" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/menos" />
```

But it is not working. Im very new in Android and I dont get to see what im doing wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //View boton1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //boton1.setOnClickListener(this);
    //View boton2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    //boton2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Edittext1);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(texto.getText().toString());
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1: texto.setText("case1");
            n++;
            break;
        case R.id.button2: texto.setText("case2");
            n--;
            break;
        default: texto.setText("default");
    }
    texto.setText(n);

}
```

}

When I run the app, it stops suddenly (unexpectly) when I click for the second time.
Can anyone give a little help? thanks for your time!

Comment: http://androidbite.blogspot.co.il/2012/11/android-count-down-timer-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 texto.setText(n);
```

This is your mistake. `n` is an int values. setText looks for a resource with the id. if not found you get `ResourceNotFoundException`.

You are using this `public final void setText (int resid)` instead of `public final void setText (CharSequence text)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Change to

```
 texto.setText(String.valueOf(n));
```

Also

```
EditText text0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edittext1);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Although casting edittext to textview is not a problem i suggest you change to  `texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edittext1);`

There is no need to initialize edittext everytime on button click.

Also remove `implements OnClickListener` coz you have `android:onClick="onClick"`